# Flatten non primary key column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a requirement to flatten non primary key column to one row with comma separated values in mysql. Let's take a simple example. There is a table called stud_sub with stud_id and sub_id as composite primary key. Now I want to have a table where stud_id will be primary key and sub_ids will be the values in the row separated by comma as shown below in stud_sub_flat table.

```
stud_sub
----------
stud_id     sub_id
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           1
2           2
3           2
3           3

stud_sub_flat
-------------
stud_id     sub_id
1           1,2,3
2           1,2
3           2,3
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: It looks like stud_sub_flat should be a VIEW rather than a TABLE.

Answer (score 4):

Try it

```
select stud_id, group_concat(sub_id) as sub_ids  from stud_sub group by stud_id
```

This select is give a output that you want.

This select query output is store in table `stud_sub_flat` using insert select query.

```
insert into stud_sub_flat (stud_id,sub_id) 
select stud_id, group_concat(sub_id) as sub_ids  from stud_sub group by stud_id
```

Ref: [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), [Insert .... select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: If you do the insert, what happens when the stud_sub table content changes later on?  The stud_sub_flat table will be out of sync! I think a better answer would be: `CREATE VIEW stud_sub_flat AS SELECT stud_id, group_concat(sub_id) AS sub_ids  FROM stud_sub GROUP BY stud_id`

Comment: @aro_tech Thank you. I know the better way is to create a VIEW, but here  Partha wants to have a table